# Moebius function and expansion in sequence $A280194$

Tags: mobius-function

For my research interest, I came accross with OEIS sequence A280194

In particular I am interested how is obtained the value $36203$ in the sequence

Expansion of:

$\frac{1}{1-\sum_{k>=1}{\mu(k)^2\cdot x^k}}$ where $\mu$ is the Moebius function.

Let $a(n)$ denote a term in the sequence OEIS
A280194. How is calculated for example $a(4)=7$?

Comment: Do long division. Only need a few terms from the series in the denominator, say up to degree $4$. The division is done with reverse degree monomial order. Long division still divides leading term by leading term, but leading terms are the ones with lowest degree, instead of largest.

Comment: $36203$ is the $17$-th term or so. I don't know which method exactly they used, but you can still do long division. Just start with the denominator up to degree $17$. They could have also used the little Maple code that is implied by the combinatorial definition of the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

You asked

> Let a(n) denote a term in the sequence Oeis A280194. How is calculated for example a(4)=7?

The [OEIS sequence A280194](https://oeis.org/A280194) entry states:

> EXAMPLE   a(4) = 7 because we have [3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2] and [1, 1, 1, 1].

This comes from the comment

> Number of compositions (ordered partitions) into squarefree parts (A005117).
> INVERT transform of the absolute value of the Möbius function (A008966). - Alois P. Heinz, Feb 11 2021

and the example shows the $7$ compositions of $4$ into squarefree parts
in reverse lexicographic order. To show that $a(5)=14$ list all of the
14 compositions of $5$ into squarefree parts

$$
\texttt{ 5 = 3+2 = 3+1+1 = 2+3 = 2+2+1 = 2+1+2 = 2+1+1+1 = 1+3+1 =}\\
\texttt{ 1+2+2 = 1+2+1+1 = 1+1+3 = 1+1+2+1 = 1+1+1+2 = 1+1+1+1+1}. $$

The interpretation as compositions into squarefree parts comes almost
directly from the name of the sequence

> Expansion of 1/(1 - Sum_{k>=1} mu(k)^2*x^k), where mu(k) is the Moebius function (A008683).

The square of the Moebius function is the indicator of squarefree numbers.

A simple example is the case of $\,1/(1 - x - x^2)\,$ which is the
generating function of the Fibonacci numbers with $\,a(n)=0\,$ if $\,n<0,\,$ $\,a(0) = 1,\,$ and $\,a(n) = a(n-1)+a(n-2) \,$ if $\,n>0.\,$
The interpretation is that $\,a(n)\,$ is the number of compositions of
$n$ into parts of $1$ and $2$ only.

Your question

> In particular I am interested how is obtained the value 36203 in the sequence

asks how to evaluate $a(17) = 36203.$ In this case it is possible to
write a program to systematically list all $36203$ compositions of
$17$. An easier method is to use the recursion which comes from the
generating function similar to the Fibonacci example. That is

$$ \texttt{ a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-3) + a(n-5) + a(n-6) + a(n-7) + a(n-10)}\\
\texttt {+ a(n-11) + a(n-13) + a(n-14) + a(n-15) + a(n-17) +}\cdots. $$

The easiest method is to use a Computer Algebra System to do the
calculation with power series.